# sub-category not showing on specific theme

Tags: category, menu, ce-1.9.2.4

When I change to other theme, it is working.
I checked header.phtml and topmenu.html but they look fine.
What am I missing??
I use magento 1.9.2.4.

Comment: may jquery no flict issue

Answer (score 0):

It was simply because varien/menu.js was commented out in page.xml when I used other extension for menu.